# ExtJS: load JSON from an external file into TreePanel

Tags: javascript, json, treeview, extjs

You can grab data from [here](http://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?4595-Creating-Ext.tree.TreePanel-from-static-JSON-data-in-one-shot&p=341626#post341626). Instead of saving JSON as a separate variable within the script file, is it possible to create a file pointer, and populate a Tree with one config option? Saving JSON in a variable does the job, but it's quite cumbersome!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use files outside of things like AIR it's a security risk and the sandbox won't allow it. You can of course keep the JSON in an external file and request it through HTTP using a TreeLoader with AsyncTreeNode and preloading children OR simply evaluate the AJAX response yourself.

Comment: Could you, please put some code up? If I pass `dataUrl: "somejsonfile.json"` within a config option, it's not going to populate the tree!